# elasticsearch-dsl - Aggregates collecting average in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-py

I'm trying to use the elasticsearch-dsl library, but unfortunately it's not well documented.

I have the following filter, which works.

First I find how far back I need my search.

```
longtime = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(pairs[p][1]) + basehrs)), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').strftime('%s.%f')
```

Then I run my search with a filter

```
s = Search(using=es, index="history", doc_type=pairs[p][0]).filter('range', timestamp={'gte': longtime})
```

After this I should need to run some aggs. I have the following but it doesn't work:

```
s = s.aggs.bucket('average', 'avg', field='ask')
```

It just returns back:

Avg(field='ask')

I also need it to do a fun calculation, not just something straightforward. I need ask + (spread / 2)

i.e.

s = s.aggs.bucket('average', 'avg', field='ask + (spread / 2')

Does anyone have any ideas?

While we're here, I need spread to be an integer type, it's currently a string. I used python to create the index in the first place; I'm happy to delete my index and start again, but I don't know how to specify the fieldtype in python when it's created.

Answer (score 0):

Whan specifying aggregations you shouldn't assign back to `s`, aggregations are modified in place.

For the scripted aggregation you need to specify a script [0] (and have scripting enabled in elasticsearch):

```
s.aggs.metric('average', 'avg', script={'inline': "doc['ask'].value + doc['spread'].value/2"})
```

0 - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-avg-aggregation.html#_script

Comment: Hi mate, I appreciate the assistance. I've been playing around with that for a few hours now and I can't get it going. I'm getting:

`{'query': {'bool': {'filter': [{'range': {'timestamp': {'gt': '1484749397.311207'}}}]}}, 'aggs': {'average': {'avg': {'script': {'inline': 'doc["ask"].value + doc["spread"].value/2'}}}}, 'sort_keys': True, 'size': 50000}`

returned when I print the dict.

Comment: oh, please just pass in the datetimes, no need to serialize them into timestamps. If you do serialize them make sure they are compatible with elasticsearch which uses millisecond precision (`timestamp * 1000` in python).

Answer (score 0):

after you do `s = s.aggs.bucket('average', 'avg', field='ask')`

do `result = s.execute()`

then your `result.aggs.to_dict()` will show you the agg result